# OnClickListener cannot be called in Fragment

Tags: android, button

My Button is linked to an OnClickListener which implemented some code to be executed if the button is clicked. When I did this in an Activity class, it works out flawlessly. However, in Fragment, this doesn't seem to be the case. Why does OnClickListener cannot be called inside a Fragment?

```
public class MarketFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.market_activity, container, false);

    Button plus1Button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.plus4_btn);
    Button minus1Button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.minus1_btn);

    plus1Button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText)     rootView.findViewById(R.id.Number1);
            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

            Zahl = Zahl + 1;
            Log.d("Zahl nach Plus Button", Integer.toString(Zahl));

            editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
        }
    });

    minus1Button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Number1);
            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            // int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

            //Zahl = Zahl - 1;

            //editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
        }
    });
```

Comment: There is no reason why an `OnClickListener` would not work in a `Fragment`. Are you returning the same `rootView` from the `onCreateView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you have to do.

- Remove final from the rootView
- Declare the EditText outside of the OnClickListener

So final modified code that should work is:

```
public class MarketFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.market_activity,container, false);


    Button plus1Button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.plus4_btn);
    Button minus1Button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.minus1_btn);
    EditText editText = (EditText)     rootView.findViewById(R.id.Number1);

    plus1Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

            Zahl = Zahl + 1;
            Log.d("Zahl nach Plus Button", Integer.toString(Zahl));

            editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
        }
    });

    minus1Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String str = editText.getText().toString();
            // int Zahl = Integer.parseInt(str);

            //Zahl = Zahl - 1;

            //editText.setText(Integer.toString(Zahl));
        }
    });
.
.
return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not returning rootView from onCreateView().

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
    .....
    ....

     return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the listener in the onActivityCreated method.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Button plus1Button = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.plus4_btn);
    plus1Button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

edit: and you should implement the View.OnClickListener

```
public class MarketFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a simple typo in there - shouldn't `rootView.findViewById(R.id.plus4_btn);` be something like `rootView.findViewById(R.id.plus1_btn);` ?